# Find documents that contain an id in an array field and have a name

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have following Collections:

```js
[
 { 
   name: "apple",
   class: [620e112a03914a837dcd7585,620e112a03914a837dcd4325]
 },
 {
   name: "orange",
   class: [620e112a03914a837dcd4325,620e112a03914a837dcd7712]
 }
]
```

I want to execute this query:

> Find all the documents which have name 'apple' and have class '620e112a03914a837dcd4325'

How are we suppose to do this in mongoose/mongodB??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your model is called `Product`, you could do it this way:

```
Product.find({name: 'apple', class: {"$in": ['620e112a03914a837dcd4325']}})
```